# Haskell Turtle - split a shell

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

Is it possible to split a Shell in Turtle library (Haskell) and do different things to either split of the shell, such that the original Shell is only run once ?

```
             /---- shell2
---Shell1 --/
            \
             \-----shell3
```

For instance, how to do

```
do
  let lstmp = lstree "/tmp"
  view lstmp
  view $ do
    path <- lstmp
    x <- liftIO $ testdir path
    return x
```

such that lstree "/tmp" would only run once.

Specifically I would like to send Shell 2 and Shell 3 to different files using output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to split a `Shell` into two separate shells that run simultaneously, unless there's some magic I don't know. But file writing is a *fold* over the contents of a shell or some other succession of things. It is built into `turtle` that you can always combine many folds and make them run simultaneously using the `Control.Foldl` material - here

```
foldIO ::  Shell a -> FoldM IO a r -> IO r  -- specializing
```

A shell is secretly a `FoldM IO a r -> IO r` under the hood anyway, so this is basically `runShell`. To do this we need to get the right `Shell` and the right combined `FoldM IO`. The whole idea of the `Fold a b` and `FoldM m a b` types from the `foldl` package is simultaneous folding.

I think the easiest way to get the right shell is just to make the `lstree` fold return a `FilePath` *together* with the result of `testdir`. You basically wrote this:

```
withDirInfo :: FilePath -> Shell (Bool, FilePath)
withDirInfo tmp = do
    let lstmp = lstree tmp
    path <- lstmp
    bool <- liftIO $ testdir path
    return (bool, path)
```

So now we can get a `Shell (Bool, FilePath)` from `/tmp` This has all the information our two folds will need, and thus that our combined fold will need.

Next we might write a helper fold that prints the `Text` component of the `FilePath` to a given handle:

```
sinkFilePaths :: Handle -> FoldM IO FilePath ()
sinkFilePaths handle = L.sink (T.hPutStrLn handle . format fp)
```

Then we can use this `Handle -> FoldM IO FilePath ()` to define two `FoldM IO (Bool, FilePath) ()`. Each will write different stuff to different handles, and we can unite them into a single simultaneous fold with `<*`. This is an independent `FoldM IO ...` and can be applied e.g. to a pure list of type `[(Bool, FilePath)]` using `L.fold` and it will write different things from the list to the different handles. In our case, though, we will apply it to the `Shell (Bool, FilePath)` we defined.

The only subtle part of this is the use of `L.handlesM` to print only the second element, in both cases, and only those filtered as directories in the other. This uses the `_2` lens and `filtered` from the lens libraries. This could probably be simplified, but see what you think:

```
{-#LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Turtle
import qualified Control.Foldl as L
import qualified System.IO as IO
import Control.Lens (_2,filtered)
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T

main = IO.withFile "tmpfiles.txt" IO.WriteMode $ \h ->
       IO.withFile "tmpdirs.txt" IO.WriteMode $ \h' -> do
        foldIO (withDirInfo "/tmp") (sinkFilesDirs h h') 

withDirInfo :: Turtle.FilePath -> Shell (Bool, Turtle.FilePath)
withDirInfo tmp = do
    let lstmp = lstree tmp
    path <- lstmp
    bool <- liftIO $ testdir path
    return (bool, path)

sinkFilePaths :: Handle -> FoldM IO Turtle.FilePath ()
sinkFilePaths handle = L.sink (T.hPutStrLn handle . format fp)

sinkFilesDirs  :: Handle -> Handle -> FoldM IO (Bool, Turtle.FilePath) ()
sinkFilesDirs h h' = allfiles <* alldirs where

  allfiles :: L.FoldM IO (Bool, Turtle.FilePath) ()
  allfiles = L.handlesM _2 (sinkFilePaths h)
  -- handle the second element of pairs with sinkFilePaths

  alldirs :: FoldM IO (Bool, Turtle.FilePath) ()
  alldirs = L.handlesM (filtered (\(bool,file) -> bool) . _2) (sinkFilePaths h')
 -- handle the second element of pairs where the first element
 -- is true using sinkFilePaths
```

Comment: Ok, that explains very nicely how to do it. The part that I was missing was understanding that writing to a file can also be a fold using 'L.sink'. Just means I have to explore more the power of Foldl !

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for something like `async` to split off your shells from the first shell and then wait for them to return. `async` is a pretty capable library that can achieve much more than the below example, but it provides a pretty simple solution to what you're asking for:

```
import Control.Concurrent.Async
import Turtle.Shell
import Turtle.Prelude

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let lstmp1 = lstree "/tmp"
  let lstmp2 = lstree "/etc"
  view lstmp1
  view lstmp2
  job1 <- async $ view $ do
    path <- lstmp1
    x <- liftIO $ testdir path
    return x
  job2 <- async $ view $ do
    path <- lstmp2
    x <- liftIO $ testdir path
    return x
  wait job1
  wait job2
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm doing stream processing, so actually I want everything to happen in sync, line by line, so I don't think async is the answer here.